# Implementing a sine or cosine wave (with probability)

Tags: r, time-series, simulation

I'm looking for simple manner to implement a special wave (sine/cosine) in R according to some probability. For example how to model the function bellow :

```
A=  runif(500,1,3)
phi=rnorm(500, 0, 1)
C=  runif(500,0,1)
Nt= rnorm(500,0,0.05)
t=  seq(1,50,length=500)
xt1= A*cos(t+phi)+C+Nt
xt2= A*sin(t+phi)+C+Nt
```

I would to creat a time series xt which takes a instant $t$, either a cosine with probability of 0.5 or a sine with a probability of 0.5

EDIT: function below
[image]

Comment: `ifelse(runif(length(t)) < 0.5, xt1, xt2)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, great answer, please answer so that I can validate your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is sufficiently handled with the vectorized version of if/else:

```
ifelse(runif(length(t)) < 0.5, xt1, xt2)
```

Caveat: this works great in most circumstances. However, `ifelse` can have side-effects. This works normally, keeping the `POSIXt` class:

```
Sys.time() + ifelse(runif(3) < 0.5, 0, 100)
# [1] "2018-10-29 12:54:08 PDT" "2018-10-29 12:54:08 PDT" "2018-10-29 12:54:08 PDT"
```

But if you are working on already-classes vectors, that class can be lost:

```
ifelse(runif(3) < 0.5, Sys.time(), Sys.time() + 100)
# [1] 1540842742 1540842842 1540842842
```

There are workarounds for this, but sometimes they are better classified as "hacks". And you can't use them if you don't realize you need to look for them. (This is generally not a factor if the vector is simply `numeric`, `integer`, `logical`, or `character`, and I'm sure some others are equally "fine".)